# Not able to set session in php

Tags: php, session

I'am not able to get session variable in php i have started session in main html page. Only if part is working rest of the else part is not giving any result.
it is giving me an error while reloading the page in header section

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\PHPMailer\extras\js\post_action.php

**post_action.php**

```
   <form method='post' id='submit_form' action="process/upload_new.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <tr>
       <td class="col-md-4">Upload Image</td> 
        <td class="col-md-8"><input name='post_image' value='<?php echo $rows["post_image"]; ?>' type="file" placeholder="Site Titlebar" class="form-control" />
            <br>
        <input name='submit' id='submit' type="submit" value='Upload Image' class="btn btn-success" />  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <p> Image Preview </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src='<?php echo $rows["post_image"]; ?>' width='100px' height='100px' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

**process/upload_new.php**

```
<?php

if($_FILES['post_image']['name'] != ''){

    $uploaded_file = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
    $exp = explode(".",$uploaded_file);
    $extension = end($exp);
    $allowed_types = array('jpg',"jpeg","png","gif");
    if(in_array($extension,$allowed_types))
    {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'])){
            $new_name = rand().".".$extension;
            $path = "../images/".$new_name;


            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'],$path))
            {
                $_SESSION['upload_success'] = "File Uploaded succesfully";
                $db_path = "images/".$new_name;
                $values = ['post_image' => $db_path]; #calling update method to update image;
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                include_once "action_page.php";
                $tablename = 'posts';
                $abc = new Demo();
                $res = $abc->edit($tablename,$values,$id);
                unset($abc);
                $_SESSION['upload_success'] = "File Uploaded succesfully"; 
                //header("location:../post_action.php?id=$id");

            }
            else
                {
                    $_SESSION['upload_error'] = "Something went wrong, file cannot be uploaded"; 
                    //header("location:../post_action.php?id=$id");
                }
        }
        else            
            {
                $_SESSION['upload_error'] = "Cannot upload file"; 
                //header("location:../post_action.php?id=$id");
            }   
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['upload_warning'] = "Please upload appropriate file type"; 
        //header("location:../post_action.php?id=$id");
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['upload_warning'] = "Please upload file"; 
    header("location:../post_action.php?id=$id");
}
```

Comment: add session_start on upload_new.php

Comment: `session_start();`. Add it on php page just after `<?php`

Comment: Why do you use single and double quotes together on one line?

Comment: @ – Manthan Dave - i have already added session_start on upload_new.php . My if block is working fine but not the else part.

Comment: thanks guys but problem solved i have created session for id .. now its working fine